Strange current shape in joule thief
I am using a -26 core material toroid (yellow-white) (from China) in inverting joule thief.
The current at the top suddenly looses/decreases an amplitude.
A diode I am using is Fr102 so for 20 kHz it should be fast enough.
Also the core heats to about 50degC.
Where can the problem occur?
Current measured on shunt placed in series with inductor:

Schematic:

Collector voltage in respect to Gnd:

Layout:

EDIT:
I tried next -26 core salvaged from old PSU and the step at top of current is still there.
Then I tried -8 core (yellow-red) and the result is much better. Also the core heats much less (about 35degC).
A current using -8 core material:


Value of shunt? Method of measurement?

@Andyaka A 0.56 ohm. I measure a voltage across it. So the top is 1.07A.

The core you are using is powdered iron rather than ferrite, right? What's the inductance you measure with 30t?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Right, it is an iron powder core. I have no indutance meter but it can be derrived from current slope: 30us, 5V, 1.07A -> 140uH

@MichalPodmanický if I were using a cheap scope to make this measurement I'd measure using two channels with one channel looking at the 5 volt rail and the other channel looking at the node between shunt and inductor. That would rule out poor CM scope problems.

(from China specified by Micrometals)

Without having looked at circuit specifics in detail I note that a micro-metal core may be far duperior to an apparent clone. Micrometal colour codes are much copied by others but the core material may be far from identical. I specified "MUST BE GENUINE" MM cores in a Taiwanese product. Clone cores overheated badly.

You mean the step, whereas triangle is expected--?
Consider the decomposition into components:

It seems you have some square aspect to the reading.
Can you see any elements in the circuit that could contribute a square wave?
Likely suspects:

Resistance in parallel with the inductor (#26 has a Q around 20 at this frequency)
Inductance in series with the resistor

Think I'll treat this as a homework problem, and leave calculating the magnitude of resistance or inductance (or how to tell them apart) as an exercise for the reader.

Yes, I mean a step at the top of peak in current waveform. I think this current loss is tranfered to heat in core since the core temperature rises to about 50C (122F).
